# React.js js files won't load at the first time only after refresh it works

Tags: reactjs

I build a website in react.js and a problem came up. I think that when I click on a page that requires a script, the first time I enter the scripts does not work. but after when I refresh the page. suddenly the data appear. I think that my JavaScripts is no loading it, but if I refresh the page and it starts working.

I put the javascript files to index.html.

I tried with helmet, i tried to load homepage with lazy method both didnt work.

This is the part of code my homepage.js. For example, data-bgimage does not seem the page first load, when i refresf the page then it shows up.

```
 <div className="no-bottom no-top" id="content">
              <div id="top" />
              <section id="section-hero" className="no-top no-bottom" data-bgimage={"url(images/background/11.jpg) left bottom"}>
                <div className="v-center">
                  <div className="container">
                    <div className="row align-items-center">
                      <div className="col-md-6">
                        <div className="spacer-single" />
                        <h6 className="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".5s"><span className="text-uppercase id-color-2"> Market</span></h6>
                        <div className="spacer-10" />
```

This is my app.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import {HashRouter as Router ,Route,Redirect,Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import TopBar from './components/TopBar';
import HomePage from './pages/home';
import LoginPage from './pages/LoginPage';
import SignUp from './pages/SignUp';
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux';

const App = ()=> {
  //static contextType = Authentication;
  const {isLoggedIn} = useSelector((store)=> ({isLoggedIn:store.isLoggedIn}));
  return (
    <div id="wrapper">
        <Router>
          
        <TopBar />
        <Switch>
        <Route forceRefresh={true} exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
        {!isLoggedIn && <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />}
        <Route exact path="/signup" component={SignUp} />

       </Switch>
        <Redirect to="/" />
        </Router>
   </div>
    
  );
};

export default App;
```

This is a screenshot of index.html :

[image]

And this is the console error ( Sometimes error is not showing, when i refresh the page error is gone. )

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue. Scripts do not load on first opening of the site. But after I refresh they are ok. I'm loading using useEffect. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Considering your files are in public folder,

Change the links path from 'js/xxxxxxx.js' to '`/`js/xxxxxx.js'.

Add `/` at the beginning of every path.